# Make a sub array based on main array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays first array is main comment and second array is sub comment.

### 1st Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [comment] => Nice Blog
            [parent_id] => 0
            [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
            [user_title] => Shaishav Desai
            [image_path] => 067da3ff3b891981caa5b5d98c44052c.png
            [cnt] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [comment] => Awesome blog
            [parent_id] => 0
            [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
            [user_title] => Lead1 Assistant
            [image_path] => 099dbe4c58606a3abf867d821e62fdf9.png
            [cnt] => 2
        )
)
```

### 2nd Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [comment] => Yes, Really good
            [parent_id] => 2
            [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
            [user_title] => Shaishav Desai
            [image_path] => 067da3ff3b891981caa5b5d98c44052c.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [comment] => Thank you
            [parent_id] => 2
            [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
            [user_title] => Lead1 Assistant
            [image_path] => 099dbe4c58606a3abf867d821e62fdf9.png
        )

)
```

Now we need an array like this with a single array based on "parent_id" and "id":

I want new array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [comment] => Nice Blog
            [parent_id] => 0
            [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
            [user_title] => Shaishav Desai
            [image_path] => 067da3ff3b891981caa5b5d98c44052c.png
            [cnt] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [comment] => Awesome blog
            [parent_id] => 0
            [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
            [user_title] => Lead1 Assistant
            [image_path] => 099dbe4c58606a3abf867d821e62fdf9.png
            [cnt] => 2
            [sub_comment] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [comment] => Yes, Really good
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
                        [user_title] => Shaishav Desai
                        [image_path] => 067da3ff3b891981caa5b5d98c44052c.png
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [comment] => Thank you
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [created] => 2018-02-20 00:00:00
                        [user_title] => Lead1 Assistant
                        [image_path] => 099dbe4c58606a3abf867d821e62fdf9.png
                    )

            )
        )

)
```

So I can easily know this comment have sub comment and display based on new array.
Would you please let me know is it possible or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have fixed array or create dynamically or more than 2 array

Comment: It's dynaminc array so it will have more than 2 value also.

Comment: and always second array as sub array of first array last value

Comment: It's totally dynamic not fixed sometime both have subarray, sometimes only one have subarray.

Comment: so what you have try for this...?

Comment: Why upvote ...? This is basic question..

Answer (score 0):

// Suppose $array1 is firts array;

// $array2 is second array

```
foreach($array2 as $subary){
    $cnt=0;
    foreach($array1 as $key=> $mainary){
        if($subary['parent_id']==$mainary['id']){
            $array1[$key]['sub_comment']=$subary;
        }
    }

}
print_r($array1);
```

Comment: Is it possible to without loop ?

Comment: No .. because you can't compare/establish relationship without loop